# Google Maps API Marker Title

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using a Fusion Table layer to display marker data.  With FT handling the markers, I dont see a way to define the title attribute on the markers.

Want to do something like this on the mouseover:
http://www.guardian.co.uk/travel/series/berlin-city-guide?intcmp=122

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this today with Fusion Tables. I suggest filing a feature request on the Google Maps API issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

There is a title that can be used but that is like a title property on any general html control check it out here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerOptions

the way guardian is doing it possibly is using a event handler on the marker and using an inforwindow something like this

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng, 
      map: map,
      title:"Hello World!"  // see how title is used
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
     infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
     infowindow.setContent(contentString); // contentString can be html as far as i  know whose style you can override
     infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

     infowindow.open(map);
  });
```